# I'm trying to remove empty strings from a list of strings but weirdly not all of them are getting removed

Tags: c#, list

I have a list of strings that I'm sending to the method. The method takes the list, iterates over it and removes all the empty strings. In the list I'm sending, there are a total of 7 blank strings but the method only seems to be removing 4 of them.

Here's the method:

```
public List<string> RemoveWhiteSpace(List<string> rawData)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rawData.Count; i++)
    {
        if (rawData[i].Length == 0)
        {
            rawData.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }

    return rawData;
}
```

Here's the list itself copied straight from the console:

```
  






@0
D=M
@1
D=D-M
@10
D;JGT
@1
D=M
@12
0;JMP
@0
D=M
@2
M=D
@14
0;JMP
```

This is the output string from the method. It fails to eliminate 3 empty strings. I tested and checked the indices of the strings which aren't being removed, they are indices:4,5 and 6. I also checked the length of these strings and they are in fact 0. I don't understand what the problem is.

```
@0
D=M
@1
D=D-M
@10
D;JGT
@1
D=M
@12
0;JMP
@0
D=M
@2
M=D
@14
0;JMP
```

Answer (score 7):

RemoveAt removes the current index, so the index of all elements behind the index you remove will be decremented.

If you want to avoid this, you could start from the end of your list:

```
for (int i = rawData.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{ 
    if (rawData[i].Length == 0)
    {
        rawData.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh wow this makes sense! thank you for your reply

Answer (score 6):

Why not let .net do the work for you?

```
list.RemoveAll(item => item.Length == 0);
```

Or better (note that we remove `null` strings as well)

```
list.RemoveAll(item => string.IsNullOrEmpty(item));
```

**Edit:** To repair your current loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rawData.Count;) // don't increment here
{
    if (rawData[i].Length == 0)
    {
        rawData.RemoveAt(i);
    }
    else
    {
        i++; // but here 
    }
}
```

**Edit 2:** If you want to keep loop, please, note that it's not efficient: whenever we remove item at index `i` we shown move items from `i + 1 ... Count - 1`. In the worst case (deleting all items) we have move `n - 1` items then `n - 2`, ... `1` items which can be slow. A better option is

```
int index = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < rawData.Count; ++i) 
  if (rawData[i].Length != 0)
    rawData[index++] = rawData[i];

rawData.RemoveRange(rawData.Count - index);
```

Comment: This is great!  I'm new to C# and programming in general so I did not know about this. Is this more efficient than using a loop?

Comment: @SmAsh: here (with a very small list) the "efficiency" is a question of *nanoseconds*; it's *readability* that's IMHO matters most. I expect the loop to be some ticks ahead

Answer (score 3):

Another option is Linq:

If you want to get rid of just empty lines:

```cs
var newData = rawData
    .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)).ToList();
```

If you want to get rid of just empty lines and lines with only whitespace:

```cs
var newData = rawData
    .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)).ToList();
```

Remember that with this code the original collection is left intact so you would need to do further processing with `newData`

Comment: Well,`IsNullOrWhiteSpace` may appear *too wide*, e.g. it'll remove `"  \t\n \r\n"` string

Comment: Yes, the reason that I selected IsNullOrWhiteSpace is that the first entry in his example has two leading spaces, perhaps this was just a copy paste error. Ill update to inform of each option

Answer (score 0):

MY guess is that you have some "slots" with consecutive empty strings, and your loop is skipping one of them - here's why.

Suppose you have a list of 4 strings, and (zero-based) indexes 1 and 2 are empty. When i = 1, it detects an empty string and removes it. The *problem* is that removing the item shifts all remaining items up one index, so the item that was at index 2 is now at index 1. But your loop counter advances to 2, and so the item at index 2 is never checked.

The simple solution is to iterate the list *backwards*:

```
for (int i=rawData.Count - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--)
{
    if (rawData[i].Length==0)
    {
        rawData.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use removeall(predicate) method as a oneliner.

```
list.RemoveAll(s => string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
```

Best regards